# Javascript move element with mousemove event 60 FPS requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css

there! i have a problem for getting `#drag` element moving smoothly.

i look at this article : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/#debouncing-mouse-events

it said that : "the problem with `mousemove` event when moving element was **mousemove event fired too much**

so, i try to used their method : using `requestAnimationFrame` + `boolean checking`.

look at this fiddle for live action : https://jsfiddle.net/5f181w9t/

HTML :

```
<div id="drag">this is draggable</div>
```

CSS :

```
#drag {width:100px; height:50px; background-color:red; transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
```

JS :

```
var el               = document.getElementById("drag"),
    startPosition    = 0, // start position mousedown event
    currentPosition  = 0, // count current translateX value
    distancePosition = 0, // count distance between "down" & "move" event
    isMouseDown      = false; // check if mouse is down or not 

function mouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // reset default behavior
    isMouseDown     = true;
    startPosition   = e.pageX; // get position X
    currentPosition = getTranslateX(); // get current translateX value
    requestAnimationFrame(update); // request 60fps animation
}    

function mouseMove(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    distancePosition = (e.pageX - startPosition) + currentPosition; // count it!  
}

function mouseUp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isMouseDown = false; // reset mouse is down boolean
}

function getTranslateX() {
   var translateX = parseInt(getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue("transform").split(",")[4]);

   return translateX; // get translateX value

}

function update() {
    if (isMouseDown) { // check if mouse is down
        requestAnimationFrame(update); // request 60 fps animation
    }
    el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + distancePosition + "px, 0, 0)";
  // move it!
}

el.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);
```

is this the correct way to accompolished it?

what's wrong with my code?

thanks

Comment: yep, what's wrong with your code ?

Comment: thanks Kaiido for commenting. really? i feel like, it's not really smooth?

Comment: On my FF it's perfectly smooth, a little bit blinking in chrome, that's true, but certainly because of this red color.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `requestAnimationFrame()` in the `mouseDown` event listener. You should do all you updates in the `mouseMove` event listener because you want to update your display when the mouse moves not when mouse clicks. Accordingly you should update all your variables under the `isMouseDown` conditional in the `update` function. i would suggest correcting the code as follows.

```js
var el               = drag,
    startPosition    = 0, // start position mousedown event
    currentPosition  = 0, // count current translateX value
    distancePosition = 0, // count distance between "down" & "move" event
    isMouseDown      = false, // check if mouse is down or not
    needForRAF       = true;  // to prevent redundant rAF calls

function mouseDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // reset default behavior
  isMouseDown     = true;
  currentPosition = getTranslateX(); // get current translateX value
  startPosition   = e.clientX; // get position X
}    

function mouseMove(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  distancePosition = (e.clientX - startPosition) + currentPosition; // count it!  
  if (needForRAF && isMouseDown) {
    needForRAF = false;            // no need to call rAF up until next frame
    requestAnimationFrame(update); // request 60fps animation
  }
}

function mouseUp(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  isMouseDown = false; // reset mouse is down boolean
}

function getTranslateX() {
  var translateX = parseInt(getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue("transform").split(",")[4]);
  return translateX; // get translateX value
}

function update() {
  needForRAF = true; // rAF now consumes the movement instruction so a new one can come
  el.style.transform = "translateX(" + distancePosition + "px)"; // move it!
}

el.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);
```

```css
#drag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="drag">this is draggable</div>
```

Check it up [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8whq035s/3/).

Comment: Why would you request the animationframe recursively inside upadte(), if mouseMove() also calls it? And wouldn't the previous request need to be cancelled, if there are more than one mouseMove event per frame?

Comment: @Ilpo Oksanen Yes you seem to be right. In this particular case the pseudo recursive feeding of the requestAnimationFrame is redundant. It's an  overlook of mine residual from my standard approach of updating the display. Thank you very much for pointing out. I will correct accordingly.

Comment: You are still stacking a lot of calls to requestAnimationFrame, which will all get executed at the same time. Use a boolean to check whether you've already handled an event in this frame,  raise it before calling rAF, and set it to false in the rAF callback. If it's already set to true, then don't call rAF.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you for your rightful comment and "code responsibly" warning. I rectified the code as suggested.

Answer (score 8):

Your code should already work fine. However, here's another way to do it:

You need to make sure you only let one `requestAnimationFrame` call go through per frame, otherwise `update()` will be called multiple times at the next `repaint`, which can cause lag and *decrease* your fps. To do this, you want to save the requested frame and on each `mousemove` event check if there's already a frame lined up. If there is, you'll want to use `cancelAnimationFrame` to cancel it and make a new request. This way `update()` is only called as often as the browser is able to render changes (I.E. 60fps in most browsers).

```
function mouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior
    isMouseDown     = true;
    startPosition   = e.pageX; // get position X
    currentPosition = getTranslateX(); // get current translateX value
}

var lastUpdateCall=null;
function mouseMove(e){
    if(isMouseDown){ //check if mousedown here, so there aren't any unnecessary animation frame requests when the user isn't dragging
        e.preventDefault(); // You probably only want to preventDefault when the user is actually dragging

        if(lastUpdateCall) cancelAnimationFrame(lastUpdateCall); //if an animation frame was already requested after last repaint, cancel it in favour of the newer event

        lastUpdateCall=requestAnimationFrame(function(){ //save the requested frame so we can check next time if one was already requested
            distancePosition = (e.clientX - startPosition) + currentPosition; // Do the distance calculation inside the animation frame request also, so the browser doesn't have to do it more often than necessary 
            update(); //all the function that handles the request
            lastUpdateCall=null; // Since this frame didn't get cancelled, the lastUpdateCall should be reset so new frames can be called. 
        });
    }
}

function update(){
    el.style.transform = "translateX(" + distancePosition + "px)";// move it!
}
```

You could also just not call `requestAnimationFrame` again if  `lastUpdateCall` isn't `null`, but that would mean you'd have to calculate the distance outside the animation frame call every time the `event` fires, or the animation would lag behind your mouse by up to 20ms. Either method is fine, I suppose.