# Mouse drag event responsiveness with and without requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, drag, requestanimationframe

I have been using the following simple code for dragging a fixed position division around the screen. It works but it isn't as responsive as when drag a browser pop-up, such as the Open File window.

As you can see, very little is taking place inside the mousemove event handler, apart from modifying the style of the top and left position of the containing element. If element is dragged from the very edge, the mouse remains about half an inch ahead of the element, especially when moved at slow-to-moderate speed, unlike the browser pop-up which sticks right to the mouse pointer.

I tried separating the element position update from the mousemove event and using requestAnimationFrame in a separate function to update the element position; and the responsiveness is no better, and maybe even a little worse. That code is provided also with a _rAF suffix in the function name.

Is there a problem in either version of the code, a better approach, or is this the best one can get for drag events in a browser?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098039/javascript-move-element-with-mousemove-event-60-fps-requestanimationframe) question is somewhat similar and I read the link it provides to HTML5 Rocks web site; and that is why I tried separating the updating of the position from the mousemove event.  Strangely, both answers to the question put the requestAnimationFrame statement back into the mousemove event, which appears to be the exact opposite of what the html5 rocks article cited was recommending and referring to as debouncing. That is, unless I am missing the point.

The code provided below works good enough but I wondered if it should be as responsive as the browser's own drag events. After just learning about snippets from luke-codewalker's comment below, I added the snippet with fixed position elements--one regular drag and one with requestAnimationFrame. I don't observe any difference between the two and both are slower to respond than when dragging one of the browser's own windows.

Thank you.

**Update (six months later)**

I'm not attempting to criticize the debouncing method in any way, and wonder if I'm not understanding it because I tried the same approach today in a custom scroll bar. I had it set up first that only on the mousemove event on the scroll bar would the scroll position of the element be changed.  That was working quite well but had a little bit of jerkiness to it, much the same as the browser scroll bars do. I thought this might be a better application of the debouncing method since the page had a lot of elements in it; so, I separted the mousemove from the screen update and used requestAnimationFrame to update the scroll position based on the mouse position, until the user let go of the mouse button.  It worked pretty well also and it was hard to tell the difference.  I thought the first way looked a bit better and had someone else look without telling her why or the difference, and she picked the first also.

Perhaps, I was expecting too much in these two applications of employing this method.  Or, I am still not understanding something and could get a smoother movement.

```js
"use strict";

     document.querySelectorAll(".drag_handle")[0].addEventListener( 'mousedown', function(event) { drag_fixed( this.parentNode, event ); }, true );

document.querySelectorAll(".drag_handle_rAF")[0].addEventListener( 'mousedown', function(event) { drag_fixed_rAF( this.parentNode, event ); }, true );


     function drag_fixed( e, evt )
       {       
         evt.stopPropagation(); 
         evt.preventDefault();

         let dx = e.offsetLeft - evt.clientX,
             dy = e.offsetTop - evt.clientY;

         document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', move, true )
         document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', stop, true );
 
         function move(evt)
           { 
             evt.stopPropagation(); 
             e.style.left = ( evt.clientX + dx ) + 'px';
             e.style.top = ( evt.clientY + dy ) + 'px';
           } // close move

         function stop(evt)
           {
             evt.stopPropagation();
             document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', move, true )
             document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', stop, true );
             e = evt = dx = dy = null;
           } // close stop

       } // close drag_fixed


 
     function drag_fixed_rAF( e, evt )
       {       
         evt.stopPropagation(); 
         evt.preventDefault();

         let dx = e.offsetLeft - evt.clientX,
             dy = e.offsetTop - evt.clientY, 
             x = evt.clientX,
             y = evt.clientY,
             r;

         document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', move, true )
         document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', stop, true );

         requestAnimationFrame( update );
 
         function move(evt)
           { 
             evt.stopPropagation(); 
             x = evt.clientX,
             y = evt.clientY;
           } // close move

         function update()
           {
             e.style.left = ( x + dx ) + 'px';
             e.style.top = ( y + dy ) + 'px';
             r = requestAnimationFrame( update );
           } // close update

         function stop(evt)
           {
             evt.stopPropagation();
             cancelAnimationFrame( r );
             document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', move, true )
             document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', stop, true );
             e = evt = dx = dy = null;
           } // close stop

       } // close drag_fixed_rAF
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; } 

     html { background-color: rgba(73,110,147,0.75); }

     body { margin: 0; }

    .container {
      position: fixed; 
      top: 50px;
      left: 50px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid black;  }

    .drag_handle, .drag_handle_rAF { 
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      color: white;
      background-color: rgb(90,120,70);
      }

    .scrollWindow {
      overflow-y: auto;
      position: absolute; 
      top: 75px; 
      left: 10px;
      width: 280px;
      height: 115px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid black; 
      background-color: rgba(255,255,225,1);
       }

    .flexContainer {
      position: absolute; 
      top: 35px; 
      left: 10px;
       }

    .data { 
      width: 100%;    
      padding: 30px 0 50px 0; }

    .close { position : absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 

    <html lang="en">

    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  
    <title>Drag Test</title> 

    <style>


    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="drag_handle">Drag Handle</div>
        <button class="close">X</button> 

        <div class="flexContainer">
           <button>Button 1</button>
           <button>Button 2</button>
           <button>Button 3</button>
        </div>

        <div class= "scrollWindow">
          <div class="data""></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container" style="left: 400px;">
        <div class="drag_handle_rAF">Drag Handle rAF</div>
        <button class="close">X</button> 

        <div class="flexContainer">
           <button>Button 1</button>
           <button>Button 2</button>
           <button>Button 3</button>
        </div>

        <div class= "scrollWindow">
          <div class="data""></div>
        </div>


    </body

    </html>
```

Comment: Could you modify your question to include a working snippet that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @luke-codewalker Yeah, sure. I changed the question code to be a complete html file with css and script. It's a little ugly but it ought to run after copy and paste. I've never used the js fiddle web site; so, this is quicker.  The fixed position window can be dragged by mousing down on any part of it that is green. Thank you. As I'm sure you know, to use the requestAnimationFrame version, just change `drag_fix` to `drag_fix_rAF` in the addEventListener.

Comment: you actually don't need to use any external sites like JSFiddle, SO has a built-in snippet functionality (https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) right there in your question.

Comment: @luke-codewalker Thanks for the information. I haven't spent much time learning about stackoverflow either. I added the snippet to the question. That is a very convenient feature. I changed the question to now have two fixed-position elements to drag, one for each drag function.

Comment: Both work fine for me with minor lagging behind the cursor. I don't see a problem or anything that could be improved directly related to the dragging of the element in your code. Not sure if this answers your question?

Comment: @luke-codewalker Thanks. I wanted to know if there is a better method for dragging that keeps the element closer to the mouse pointer. That article makes debouncing sound as if it should make a signficant difference but I don't observe one. It seems to be a change between firing mutliple times per second on mousemove versus firing 60 times per second on mousedown for rAF. Perhaps, there is a difference when there is more to process on each event. Also would like to understand why there is a lag in the js. Is it simply due to the time needed for the interpretation of the js, since not compiled?

Comment: You're right about the difference in firing rate but afaik there is not much to improve here. The question where the lag is coming from leads somewhere else and I would avoid starting a conversation about it here in the comments (there are other places for that). My guess and final contribution to this here is that it hasn't so much to do with interpreting JavaScript but more with re-rendering the DOM (https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-the-rendering-engine-and-tips-to-optimize-its-performance-7b95553baeda).

Comment: If you have nothing more than this code running, chances are you won't see the difference no. Throttling would be visible only if the code running was taking more time than what the rate allows. Let's say your mousemove event fires every 8ms max, then throttling would be visible if your code took more than these 8ms, and that you had several such event to fire every frames. Here, you are not doing anything that requires a lot of calculations, this repaint can be done several times a frame and the browser has nothing else to do.

Comment: Start adding transparency, more layers in your elements, CSS filters, box-shadows and an endless animation in the background and there you'll see the advantages of throttling on the paint-frames.

Comment: @Kaido Thank you.  Does this mean that as long as there is no time-consuming code running at each mousemove event, better movement  can be produced by updating the position each mousemove event than using the throttling?  I misunderstood the concept.  I thought that there were a maximum of 60 repaints per second and by requesting an animation frame the two events sort became in sync with one another.

Comment: @Kaido But, if understand you correctly, every change in position triggered by a mousemove event generates a repaint, and that can be more often than 60 per second.  That would explain why it appears that the non-throttled scroll method moves more smoothly than the throttled in this simple case. Thanks again. It makes more sense now.

Comment: Well no, it should not cause a *repaint*, sorry I was not clear enough (nor awaken) but it will cause reflows and a lot of calculations every mousemove. Repaint should be triggered only once per screen refresh (usually @60FPS). But I didn't say that the throttled one should perform less good than the first one, it should be about the same if the operation is made fast enough and better otherwise. I personaly can't see a difference. So use the throttled version, for anything that is graphical you'll want to stick with rAF anyway, be it to save trees.

Comment: @Kaido Thanks for the additional explanation.  In the example code, I observe no difference either; but, in the scroll bar case I mentioned, the non-rAF version appears to work better but I don't understand how that is possible.  For adjusting the scroll position in response to mousemove events on a custom scroll bar, it may no be a good idea to use the rAF version since most of us hold the mouse button down while reading and scrolling the page. During that interval of time, the rAF will be repeatedly invoked, I assume 60 timer per second even when mouse is stationary.